# Identify cycles in the graph (containing 2 nodes, 3 nodes...n nodes) using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to identify all the cycles in my graph. I would like some query which will give me the cycles between 2 nodes, another query which will give me the cycles between 3 nodes ... until n nodes.

I tried some queries but I don't know how to show only cycles with 2 nodes, then only cycles with 3 nodes. Instead, I can show all the cycles.

```
MATCH
  (m1:Disease)-[]->(m2:Disease),
  cyclePath=shortestPath((m2)-[*1..10]->(m1))
WITH
  m1, nodes(cyclePath) as cycle
WHERE id(m1) = apoc.coll.max([node in cycle | id(node)])
RETURN m1.id, cycle ;
```

I expect to have more queries which will give me only cycles with 2 nodes, then with 3 nodes...n nodes(until the max cycle was identified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple way to get all cycles of length 2:

```
MATCH p=(m1:Disease)-[*2]->(m1)
RETURN NODES(p) AS cycle
```

To get cycles of other lengths, just replace `2` in the query with the desired length.

*NOTE: This query can return the same node cycle multiple times, but with a different start/end node. For example, 1 -> 2 -> 1 and 2 -> 1 -> 2.*

Comment: to make the path distinct i tried: MATCH  p=(m1:Intervention)-[*3]->(m1) with distinct p 
RETURN count( NODES(p)) and MATCH  p=(m1:Intervention)-[*3]->(m1)  
RETURN count( distinct NODES(p)) but they are not performing

Comment: would an index help me speed up the query in this case?

Comment: No, indexing would not help.